# Can anyone please explain the output??? I just started learning kotlin so please be as detailed as you can be, thanks

Tags: java, android, kotlin

- does add() has low priority than set()?
- can mutablelist and arraylist can be differentiated using capacity/size???

```java
fun main(args: Array<String>) {

    //get() and set()
    var arrOne:MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(3, 7, 8)   //how does '3', '7' and '8' work?
    arrOne.add(11)
    arrOne.add(43)
    arrOne.add(35)
    arrOne.add(47)
    arrOne.set(0, 23)
    arrOne.set(1, 34)
    arrOne.set(2, 56)
    arrOne.set(3, 66)
    arrOne.set(4, 76)
    print(arrOne)
    println("\n" + arrOne.get(2))

    val arrTwo:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>(3) //how does '3' work?
    println(arrTwo.size)
    arrTwo.add("x")
    arrTwo.add("t")
    arrTwo.add("c")
    arrTwo.add("g")
    arrTwo.set(1, "y")
    arrTwo.set(2, "z")
    println(arrTwo.size)
    print(arrTwo)
    println("\n" + arrTwo.get(0))
}
```

Comment: why do you think that `add` has lower priority than `set`? different functionality but the statements are executed in the order they are written

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger - yup, got that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really understand what you're trying to say, but anyway.

`mutableListOf` is a *function* which create a `MutableList<T>` using the input arguments as initial values. That means the line

```
mutableListOf<Int>(3, 7, 8)
```

will output a `List<Int>` such as `[3, 7, 8]`

---

`ArrayList<String>(3)` means "*create an ArrayList container with an initial capacity of 3 elements*". That means the line

```
val arrTwo:ArrayList<String> = ArrayList<String>(3)
```

will output a `List<String>` such as `[]`

Both can be mutated after creation, and both are subject to `IndexOutOfBoundsException` using `set` or `get` (`ArrayList` extends `MutableList`)

Answer (score 1):

@LppEdd - thanks I figured it out

```
var arrOne:MutableList<Int> = mutableListOf<Int>(3) //will result in [3]
//add() extends the list
arrOne.add(11)  //[3, 11]
arrOne.add(43)  //[3, 11, 43]
arrOne.add(35)  //[3, 11, 43, 35]
arrOne.add(47)  //[3, 11, 43, 35, 47]
//set() replace the value at the given index
arrOne.set(0, 23)   //[23, 11, 43, 35, 47]
arrOne.set(1, 34)   //[23, 34, 43, 35, 47]
arrOne.set(2, 56)   //[23, 34, 56, 35, 47]
arrOne.set(3, 66)   //[23, 34, 56, 66, 47]
```